# Difficult Random

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, random

how to (even logically) random **at least one** e.g. Id from database which has specified column value?

I mean I have in database table id, question id, answer text value and bool (if answer is correct) columns and I want to get e.g. three answers Ids, that (**at least**) one of them is correct.

Many thanks for your help in advice!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you please specify how you access database in your application? Give some code of how you retrieve your data to select, for example, one question.

Comment: It's MS SQL. But I'd like to know just how to do it, I don't need any code.

Comment: I know I have to check how many correct answers the question has. Then I need to random how many correct answers to display. And I want to know how to mix these correct answers with incorrect

Comment: This should work for a specified question, or can the *x* answers be for completely unrelated questions?

Comment: @SWeko of course for specified question (by questionid).

Comment: And from the selected answers, more than one of them can be correct? If this is a multiple choice thing, I do not think that's a nice user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to make a multiple choice thing, and display *x* out of *y* answers where, out of those *y*, *c* are correct, and *w* are wrong (*c+w=y*).

I would suggest using 2 queries, first get a random correct answer, and then get *x-1* incorrect answers. I would recommend against using two or more correct answers, as it will just confuse the user.

To get the correct answer, you could do:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID 
FROM Answers 
WHERE QuestionID =@QuestionID -- parameter supplied from code
  AND IsCorrect = 1 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

After that do

```
SELECT TOP 3 ID  -- assuming the X = 4 value is hardcoded in the application
FROM Answers 
WHERE QuestionID =@QuestionID -- parameter supplied from code
  AND IsCorrect = 0
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

If you do want to include any other answer, including a correct one, you could do

```
SELECT TOP 3 ID
FROM Answers 
WHERE QuestionID = @QuestionID
  AND ID != @ID -- where ID is the ID of the question from the first query
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Since the questions won't have a large answer set (I guess not more that 10 or 20), using NEWID() on each row will not be very bad for performance.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm) to do it for several DB.

```
SELECT TOP 3 id FROM yourtable WHERE isCorrect = 1 ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: And expect horrible perforamnce for larger data sets - it has t oget all the rows and order them. MUCH better: pull all ID's into an Array in Memory, then get a random on the index of those id's - a LOT faster if you Cache the Array between calls.

Comment: This is code to choose in random order EXACTLY 3 correct answers. Am I right? 
I need something other. E.g. randomize 5 questions, for each question randomize 3 answers, that random num of them (but at least one) is correct

Comment: @TomTom I like your answer - thank you so much. But is there any other, simplier way to do it?

Comment: OK. Can you provide tables structure exactly, please.

Comment: @user1900685 EVEN easier? Come on - and no, there is not.

Comment: @TomTom "...TOP 3...WHERE isCorrect = 1" doesn't select ONLY CORRECT answers??? you're sure?

Comment: What? I don't understand you.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I think this is query to choose in random order EXACTLY 3 correct answers. Am I right?

Comment: this query does not give the incorrect answers.May be you should use UNION ,select top 1 from ...where iscorrect =1  order by NEWID () UNION select top 2  from ... where iscorrect=0 order by NEWID() or the other way TOP 2 for correct and TOP 1  for incorrect

Comment: Yes you are right. I told you to provide tables structure. Is is possible?

Comment: table answers has the following columns: Id, QuestionID, Answer, IsCorrect

Comment: Are your questions in separate table? If yes i assume, provide its structure too.

Comment: questions table: Id, Question